# "unix:10.0" in DISPLAY variable

Tags: x11

We are using Oracle Secure Global desktop to provide remote access to the Solaris desktop. It sets the `DISPLAY` variable to `unix:10.0`.

It seems to be working as if the `DISPLAY` was set to `localhost:10.0`. What does "unix" mean here?

Is it a common usage or something specific to SGD? As far as I know, usually `DISPLAY` is set in the form `[hostname or IP]:[screen]`.

Comment: Looks to me like unix just might be the hostname of the computer X11 is sending it's display to.

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonably common to see this.  It means "use a unix-domain socket" instead of a TCP/IP socket.  These "unix domain" sockets show up in the file system.  For instance, on my old Slackware 11.0 system, the Unix domain socket has the file name /tmp/.X11-unix/X0

```
12 % ls -ltr /tmp/.X11-unix
total 0
srwxrwxrwx 1 root users 0 2011-07-19 18:07 X0=
```

Note the 's' in the mode: that's "socket".  I seem to recall other X11s putting the unix-domain socket in /tmp/ directly.

Using a unix-domain socket for X11 traffic can be quite a bit faster, and probably a lot more secure than flinging the traffic over TCP-IP

Comment: Shouldn't it be `unix/:10` then? The format is `[transport/]host:[:]server[.screen]`, with host blank for local. (The extra optional `:` is to support the old method for differentiating tcp from decnet)

Comment: @Random832 I'm not sure what the exact syntax is, but X.org Xlib accepts `unix:0` as a synonym of `unix/:0`.

Comment: To add to this answer: using a unix socket means that the X server and the client are running on the same machine. Under most modern X implementations, this allows the client and the server to operate via shared memory instead of via network-style messages. Shared memory enables many optimisations, which are especially important when viewing video or drawing 3D images.

Comment: @Gilles Is this documented anywhere? I went and looked up the source (what I _thought_ was the source), since the format wasn't well-documented, and it doesn't _seem_ to support this being a synonym

Comment: I was under the impression that those optimisations are triggered whenever the local host is used as a display server, even if TCP is used. I remember reading this in some manual back in the XFree86 days.