# What is `/tmp/.X11-unix/`?

Tags: x11

I asked Google the same question and didn't like the results I got.

What is `/tmp/.X11-unix/`?

Comment: Wow, I was going to ask you what you didn't like about them... but those are some pretty terrible results.

Comment: Do you run Xvnc?

Comment: @py4on I do not think so, I ask because of my interest in running graphical apps inside a docker container, to which this mentions forwaring this x11 socket to the container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25334301/1695680

Comment: Terrible?  Really?  In my part of the world the second search result is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57138/ off this very WWW site.

Comment: @JdeBP indeed, but the title an excerpt give you no reason to click it—looks like troubleshooting some random problem. Of course now *this* question shows up, so Google is fixed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On my fairly up-to-date Arch laptop, `/tmp/.X11-unix/` is a directory with one entry: `X0`, a [Unix-domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

The X11 server (usuall `Xorg` these days) communicates with clients like `xterm`, firefox, etc via some kind of reliable stream of bytes. A Unix domain socket is probably a bit more secure than a TCP socket open to the world, and probably a bit faster, as the kernel does it all, and does not have to rely on an ethernet or wireless card.

My X11 server shows up as:

```
bediger    294   293  0 Apr09 tty1     01:23:26 /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.aK3Lrv5hMV
```

The "-nolisten tcp" keeps it from opening TCP port 6000 for communications.

The command `lsof -U` can tell you what processes are using which Unix domain sockets. I see `Xorg` as connected to `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`.

Comment: Was just about to link to another of your answers! http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20380/109083

Comment: Not to nitpick but I doubt a unix local socket has any performance advantages over a *local* TCP socket (which doesn't use a hardware interface, and is also 100% kernel).

Comment: @goldilocks - an interesting assertion.

Comment: @goldilocks: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973942/performance-tcp-loopback-connection-vs-unix-domain-socket

Comment: @Max I stand corrected!  *Although* it is not for the reasons cited by Bruce, but because of the overhead for the kernel's TCP stack.

Comment: I noticed that when trying to run X in docker, it only uses abstract unix domain sockets, without needing the actual `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` inside the container.

Answer (score 14):

The X server has several ways of communicating with X clients (apps). The most common one to use, at least on the same machine, is a Unix-domain socket.

A Unix-domain socket is like the more familiar TCP ones, except that instead of connecting to an address and port, you connect to a *path*. You use an actual file (a socket file) to connect.

The X server puts its socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix`:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 18 18:03 /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

Note the `s` in front of the permissions, which means its a socket. If you have multiple X servers running, you'll have more than one file there.

At least with the Linux manpages, more details about sockets (in general) can be found in `man 7 socket`. Details about Unix-domain sockets are in `man 7 unix`. Note that these pages are programmer-focused.

Comment: Is it safe to delete the socket files?

Answer (score 1):

/tmp/.X11-unix/X{n} are where X server put listening AF_DOMAIN sockets. Near the same place are /tmp/.X{n}-lock being locks. As is discussed in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=503181 this scheme is not FHS good.