# Why put X0 socket in /tmp (.x11-unix)? Can I move it somewhere else?

Tags: x11

I'd got a habit of clearing `/tmp` directory, after all it is "storage with a short lifetime" ([What is the difference between /tmp and /var/tmp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp)). Recently I've noted one app does not start fully, as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612672/5499118. After some search I've found more about socket file [What is `/tmp/.X11-unix/`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196677/what-is-tmp-x11-unix). I'm just curious, why put X11 socket type file in `/tmp`? How did it came into Unix?

How can I move it somewhere in a way to preserve full functionality? (renaming `.X11-unix` resulted in same issue as deleting). Recreating it by `python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/tmp/.X11-unix/X0')"` from https://serverfault.com/questions/358866/create-unix-named-socket-from-the-command-line did not help to resolve the error.